# Redefining variable according to Text Box Error

Tags: c#, forms, variables, compiler-errors

I'm new to coding and C# so sorry if this is a stupid question.

I need to redefine a variable according to a text box (user input) and I am getting an error

```
int age;
private void Age_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       //saves age in years
       age = Age_TextChanged.int;
   }
```

It is erroring on line "age = Age_TextChanged.int;" on the int bit

The error is as followed

Identifier expected; 'int' is a keyword

First off, what does this mean, secondly, how do I fix it?

Comment: I guess you need `age = int.Parse(Age.Text);`.

Comment: there is no such property called "int" on your textbox. there is a Text property for which you need to convert to an integer using the Convert.ToInt32 and assigning it to your variable "age"

Comment: Please use `TryParse`, it's a little safer.

Comment: And there is certainly no `int` property on the `Age_TextChanged` method!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, the error message is trying to point out that you have asked for something that does not exist.  As an additional bit of information, it also points out that `int` is a keyword, and is not suitable as a variable name.

If you have entered a number into a text box and would like the integer equivalent in a variable of that type, you would need to use `Int32.TryParse()` to attempt to convert that `String` into an `Int32`.

Take my advice:  name your controls and variables better.  It will make things much easier for you as you progress.  I have adjusted my example as such:

```
Int32 iAge;
private void txtAge_TextChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Saves age in years...
    if (!Int32.TryParse(txtAge.Text, out iAge))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Conversion of '{0}' to Int32 failed!", txtAge.Text), "Bad Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    }
    else
    {
        //it parsed into the Int32, so do something with it...
    }
}
```